# External javascript working in simulator but not in ios device

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, titanium

I am using Titanium sdk 3.02 and iOS SDK 6.1. Currently facing an issue with the external javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="test.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 testing_function();
</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

This function is working fine in simulator but nothing happens in device.Please suggest some solution to work it with device as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the .JS file is located in the same directory as your HTML file. Also try to browse directly to the .JS (from the device) file to make sure you can reach it.

Comment: i am making webview in app.js and the test.full.js is lying on the same path as app.js and i am setting webview html equal to the above html string.

Answer (score 0):

How did you open your base HTML file? Because the UIWebView

```
– loadHTMLString:baseURL:
```

function must be well paramterised (the source must be available relative to the baseURL).
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:

Your .js is available using the same path, as yout HTML file?

Comment: You can try to debug it running on device using Safari. Can you see the .js file between the resources of the page? (Detailed description:https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html)